# Foursquare asp.net samples

Tags: asp.net, json, foursquare

I'm pretty new with JSON and i'm a little confused...
What I'm trying to do is to use the userless access for foursquare api, to get the venues of a location. Can you please show me a similar example in .net?

Comment: leonida, this sound more like Greek than understanding question :) You need to explain more thinks, maybe focus to the real problem because I do not think that anyone can help you with this question. If there is a question for foursquare samples, then I think that you need to direct ask from this company to give you the sample and the SDK

Answer (score 0):

you may have more luck using one of the community contributed .net libraries. See https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/libraries for details.